# macOS version 12.3.1: how to quit ScreenSaverEngine by using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, screensaver

I use code in mac shell,but it make my computer become black screen:
`open -a ScreenSaverEngine.app; sleep 5; osascript -e 'tell application "ScreenSaverEngine" to quit'`

Answer (score 0):

Quitting the Screen Saver is easy, but loginning back will require the user password. You have to grant 2 permissions to Terminal.app as well, when first running the osacript bellow. 1) Permissions to control the System.Events.app, 2) permissions to control computer (that is, to be able to send keystrokes):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"
    tell screen saver preferences
        start
        delay 5
        stop
    end tell
    delay 1
    keystroke "YourUserPasswordHere" & return
end tell'
```

Other way is: **uncheck Require password after sleep or screen saver begins** in the General tab of Security&Ptivacy pane of System Preferences. Then you don't need login back.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"
    tell screen saver preferences
        start
        delay 10
        stop
    end tell
end tell'
```

Note: you can retain iCloud keychain in the pop up dialog.

Comment: thanks, but We do not have permission to obtain the permission of System Events，Are there any other possible ways

Comment: Other way is:   uncheck **Require password after sleep or screen saver begins** in the General tab of Security&Ptivacy pane of System Preferences. Then you don't need login back.

Comment: I hope my program can automatically exit ScreenSaverEngine after it finds out that ScreenSaverEngine is running, such as using appscript, password also needs to be considered